# NameError: name 'account_activation_sent' is not defined

Tags: python, django

Me devuelve un error y no consigo solucionarlo. Parece que no reconoce la ruta del archivo **account_activation_sent.html** pero no estoy seguro.

**Error:**

```
File "/home/retegi/Documents/proyectos/project/project/applications/users/urls.py", line 37, in <module>
url(r'^account_activation_sent/$', account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
```

NameError: name 'account_activation_sent' is not defined

**Urls.py**

```
 url(r'^account_activation_sent/$', account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
```

**Ruta de carpetas:**

project > templates > users >account_activation_sent.html

Comment: account_activation_sent es tomado por Python como una variable. Parece que cuando la busca, no la encuentra. De ahí el error. Si el código que pasaste es el completo, el error es evidente. En ningún lado creas la variable account_activation_sent.

Comment: Igual, sospecho que no has pasado el código completo, pues url tampoco está definido. Podrías colocar, no el codigo completo, si no uno donde el error aparesca por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes compartir como estas importando account_activation_sent en tu users/urls.py? y tu view account_activation_sent.

Es importante que compartas el código completo y no solo partes ya que así esta difícil saber que paso.

Por lo que sospecho tu error es que no estas importando correctamente el view en tu urls.py, deberías de tener algo así en la parte superior de tu urls.py:

```
from users.views import account_activation_sent
```